# stack data based on column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i am in python i have a data frame like this contain sub_id refer to patient_id, hour_measure from 1 to 22 and other patient's measurement

```
  subject_id  |   hour_measure     heart rate     |  urinecolor |  blood pressure  
     --------------------------------------------------------                
        3        |  1                   40        |  red        |  high
        3        |  2                   60        |  red        |  high
        3        |  ..                  ..        |  ..         |  ..
        3        |  22                  90        |  red        |  high

        4        |  3                   60        |  yellow     |  low
        4        |  3                   60        |  yellow     |  low  
        4        |  22                  90        |  red        |  high
```

i want to group sub_id measurement by max min skew,etc for numeric features and first and last value for categorical

i write the follwing code

```
df= pd.read_csv(path)
df1 = (df.groupby(['subject_id','hour_measure'])
        .agg([ 'sum','min','max', 'median','var','skew']))
f = lambda x: next(iter(x.mode()), None)
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df2 = df.groupby(['subject_id','hour_measure'])[cols].agg(f)
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, ['mode']])
print (df2) 
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).unstack().reorder_levels([0,2,1],axis= 1)
print (df3)          
df3.to_csv("newfile.csv")
```

it give me the grouping for every hour

i try to make it group only with subject id only

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['subject_id'])
        .agg([ 'sum','min','max', 'median','var','skew']))
```

it also give me the same output , and calculate the statistics for every hour as follows

```
     subject_id  |     heart rate_1     |  heartrate_2 .... 
     --------------------------------------------------------                
                |  min    max     mean  | min   max   mean ....               
        3
        4
```

i want the out put to be as the following

```
     subject_id  |     heart rate        |  repiratotry rate  |urine color
     --------------------------------------------------------                
                 |  min  |  max   | mean  | min |  max |  mean ..|. first |  last 
        3            50     60      55     40     65      20     | yellow |  red
```

any one can tell how can i edit the code to give the wanted output
any help will appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me know if this gets you close to what you're looking for. I did not run into your issue with grouping by every hour so I'm not sure if I understood your question completely.

```py
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "subject_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        "hour_measure": [1, 22, 12, 5, 18, 21, 8, 18, 4],
        "blood_pressure": [
            "high",
            "high",
            "high",
            "high",
            "low",
            "low",
            "low",
            "low",
            "high",
        ],
    }
)
# sort out numeric columns before aggregating them
numeric_result = (
    df.select_dtypes(include="number")
    .groupby(["subject_id"])
    .agg(["min", "max", "mean"])
)

# sort out categorical columns before aggregating them
categorical_result = (
    df.set_index(["subject_id"])
    .select_dtypes(include="object")
    .groupby(["subject_id"])
    .agg(["first", "last"])
)

# combine numeric and categorical results
result = numeric_result.join(categorical_result)
```

```
                 hour_measure                blood_pressure
                    min max       mean          first  last
subject_id
1                     1  22  11.666667           high  high
2                     5  21  14.666667           high   low
3                     4  18  10.000000            low  high
```

Comment: yes . it works and give me what i want in little time in-spite of data volume, thanks ..